Why \s does not terminate search in regex
Trying to extract

510228


from

Arve nr.:_510228
Kuupäev:_17.04.2024


using regex
(?si)(Arve nr[\s_:.]*)(?<arvenumber>.*)[\s_].*?

in C# .NET 8
finds
510228 
Kuupäev:_17.04.2024

Why [\s_] does not terminate match ?
How to get proper result 510228?
Testcase is in
https://regex101.com/r/lwgzBO/1

The pattern ’.’ catch everything including the newline character since you are using the single-line option (?si) in the beginning. You could use /S instead. /S catch everything except whitespace.  (?si)(Arve nr[\s_:.])(?\S)
